# Previously hidden select dropdowns crashing the webview when focused upon

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I have a div panel that is hidden when a page is first shown. Inside the div are a few html dropdowns (select tags). When I make the div visible (via javascript) and focus into one of the dropdowns, I get the following logcat error:
11-04 03:58:49.136: A/libc(18437): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
Then, the app just crashes and the webview disappears. I confirmed that this happens when the parent div is initially invisible (display:none). If the div is visible at first, all works fine, even if the div is hidden subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

This may be ages too late, but have you tried upgrading the device from 4.0.3 to 4.1.2? I had the same problem and the only way I could fix it was with an upgrade to the device OS.